# How to "star" messages or mark them as important in iPad mail app?

Tags: ipad, ios, email, gmail, folders

I would like to mark messages as "important" in the iPad mail app via my gmail account. The app can move messages to a new folder, so I can put them in Gmail's "starred" folder, but that moves it out of the current label. How can I "star" messages on the iPads email app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the release of iOS 5, it it possible to flag messages using the "Mark" dropdown menu.

Comment: Im using iOS 6.1 and still only have "Mark as unread". 